# how to find the probability density function of $Y=X^2$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

How to find the probability density function of $Y=X^2$? 
Variable $X$ is uniform in $(0, 1)$.
I'm not really sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ has PDF $f$, then for any measurable function $g$,

$$E(g(X))=\int_\Bbb R g(x)f(x)\mathrm dx$$

Conversely, if you can write $E(g(X))$ in such a form, then $f$ is the PDF of $X$.

Now, apply this to $Y=X^2$, $f$ being the PDF of your X, which is uniform, hence $f(x)=1_{[0,1]}(x)$:

$$E(g(Y))=E(g(X^2))=\int_\Bbb R g(x^2)f(x)\mathrm dx=\int_0^1g(x^2)\mathrm dx$$

Apply the change of variable $x^2=u$:

$$E(g(Y))=\int_0^1 g(u)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}\mathrm du=\int_\Bbb R g(u)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}1_{[0,1]}(u)\mathrm du$$

And the PDF of $Y$ is thus

$$f_Y(u)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}1_{[0,1]}(u)$$

---

Another approach, with the CDF of $X$, which is $P(X\leq x)=x$ for $x\in [0,1]$.

Then for $u\in[0,1]$, $P(Y\leq u)=P(X^2\leq u)=P(X\leq \sqrt{u})=\sqrt{u}$.
Just take the derivative of this to get the PDF of $Y$.